# Response de webservice no devulve ningun valor PHP

Tags: php, webservice

Estoy generando una consulta a un webservice en el cual como response me entrega un .zip codificado en base64 para que yo pueda decodificarlo y obtener el .zip como tal, con zip pequeños no tengo ningún problema y el response lo recibo sin ningún problema pero, al hacer un request donde el response va a ser un zip pesado, no recibo ninguna respuesta.

probando con el programa SuapUI, este si me da respuesta sin importar el tamaño, me faltara algo en mi código?

Anexo código y espero puedan ayudarme, saludos!

```php
require("conexion.php");

    include('phpqrcode/qrlib.php');
    include('pdf_cert_encabezado.php');

    include('lib/nusoap.php');
    $client = new nusoap_client('CertificadosBasica.wsdl','true');

    $err = $client->getError();

    if ($err) { 
        echo 'Error en Constructor' . $err ; 
    }

    $numeroLote = $_POST['numeroLote'];
    $usuario = "usuario";
    $password = "password";

    //Generamos consulta para obtener el nombre del zip
    $resultados = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM lote_ref WHERE numLote = '$numeroLote'");

    foreach($resultados as $fila){
        $nombre_zip = $fila['nombre_zip'];
    }

    //generamos la consulta al webservice para poder descargar el XML con el sello SEP.
    $param2 = array("numeroLote" => $numeroLote, "autenticacion" => array("usuario" => $usuario, "password" => $password));



    $result2 = $client->call('descargaCertificadosBasica', array('descargaCertificadosBasicaRequest' => $param2));


    $loteRetorno = "";
    $certificadosBase64 = "";
    $mensaje = "";


    if (empty($result2['numeroLote'])) {
        $mensaje = utf8_encode($result2['mensaje']);    
        echo $mensaje."<br><br>";
        echo "no estoy obteniendo respuesta";
    }else {
        $loteRetorno = $result2['numeroLote'];
        $certificadosBase64 = $result2['certificadosBase64'];
        //echo $loteRetorno."<br><br>";
        //echo $certificadosBase64;

        $file = base64_decode($certificadosBase64);

        //echo $certificadosBase64;

        $extension = ".zip";


        //toma el archivo, su nombre y la extension y genera el archivo en la carpeta selecciona
        $myfile = fopen("xml_cert_firmado/".$nombre_zip."firmado".$extension, "w") or die ("unable to open file!");
        fwrite($myfile, $file);
        fclose($myfile);

 }
```

Comment: quiza podrias revisar al de: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit

Comment: tambien podrias ver si tu libreria por defecto delimita el maximo de response

Comment: he revisado el manual de php y aun aumentando la cache, sigue sin funcionar. de que forma podria refisar el maximo del response de la libreria?